# react-draggableのnpmインストール時にエラーが発生してインストールできない。

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui

## 困っていること

react-draggableというパッケージを既存のReactのプロジェクトにnpmインストールしようとするとエラーが発生してインストールできず困っております。

## 教えていただきたいこと

1. react-draggable（の安定動作版）をインストールする方法。
2. なぜインストールできないのか。

## やったこと

#### 実行コマンド

下記のコマンドを実行しました。
`npm install react-draggable`

この際にエラーが発生しました。
エラーメッセージは「エラーメッセージ」で後述しております。

#### その他事前に行った関連していると思われる事象

エラーメッセージに出ている`^4.0.0-alpha.57`は、以前にインストール、手を入れた`@material-ui/lab`のバージョンなのでそれが関係していると思われます。
手を入れた理由は、`package.json`のバージョンが`*`のままだとGitHub Actionsのビルド時にエラーが起きてしまっていたからです。
変更内容は下記です。

package.json

```
    "@material-ui/lab": "*", // 変更前（インストール時）
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",// 変更後
```

package-lock.json

```
      "version": "4.0.0-alpha.57", // 変更前（インストール時）
      "version": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",// 変更後
```

## エラーメッセージ

※プロジェクト名は`{プロジェクト名}`、ユーザーネームは`{ユーザー名}`に置き換えています。

VSCodeのターミナル

```
MyMacBookAir:｛プロジェクト名｝ {ユーザー名}$ npm install react-draggable
npm ERR! Invalid Version: ^4.0.0-alpha.57

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/｛ユーザー名｝/.npm/_logs/2021-04-26T06_50_54_272Z-debug.log
```

上記`2021-04-26T06_50_54_272Z-debug.log`の中身

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   '/Users/{ユーザー名}/.nodebrew/node/v14.15.5/bin/node',
0 verbose cli   '/Users/{ユーザー名}/.nodebrew/current/bin/npm',
0 verbose cli   'install',
0 verbose cli   'react-draggable'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.8.0
2 info using node@v14.15.5
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 2ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:/Users/{ユーザー名}/.nodebrew/node/v14.15.5/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 4ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 4ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:/Users/{ユーザー名}/Documents/Sandbox/｛プロジェクト名｝/.npmrc Completed in 2ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 4ms
11 timing config:load:file:/Users/{ユーザー名}/.npmrc Completed in 5ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 5ms
13 timing config:load:file:/Users/{ユーザー名}/.nodebrew/node/v14.15.5/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 2ms
17 timing config:load Completed in 20ms
18 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 20ms
19 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
20 timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 3ms
21 timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 2ms
22 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
23 timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 1ms
24 timing npm:load Completed in 30ms
25 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
26 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
27 timing idealTree:init Completed in 1489ms
28 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 4ms
29 silly idealTree buildDeps
30 silly fetch manifest @material-ui/lab@^4.0.0-alpha.57
31 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
32 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@material-ui%2flab 1711ms (from cache)
33 silly fetch manifest @material-ui/core@latest
34 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@material-ui%2fcore 103ms (from cache)
35 silly fetch manifest @types/react@^16.8.6 || ^17.0.0
36 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2freact 98ms (from cache)
37 silly fetch manifest react@latest
38 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/react 59ms (from cache)
39 silly fetch manifest react-dom@latest
40 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dom 59ms (from cache)
41 silly fetch manifest react-draggable@*
42 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/react-draggable 628ms (from cache)
43 timing idealTree Completed in 4210ms
44 timing command:install Completed in 4238ms
45 verbose stack TypeError: Invalid Version: ^4.0.0-alpha.57
45 verbose stack     at new SemVer (/Users/{ユーザー名}/.nodebrew/node/v14.15.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver/classes/semver.js:38:13)
45 verbose stack     at compare (/Users/{ユーザー名}/.nodebrew/node/v14.15.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver/functions/compare.js:3:32)
45 verbose stack     at Object.gte (/Users/{ユーザー名}/.nodebrew/node/v14.15.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver/functions/gte.js:2:30)
45 verbose stack     at Arborist.[canPlaceDep] (/Users/{ユーザー名}/.nodebrew/node/v14.15.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:1552:53)
45 verbose stack     at Arborist.[placeDep] (/Users/{ユーザー名}/.nodebrew/node/v14.15.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:1277:36)
45 verbose stack     at /Users/{ユーザー名}/.nodebrew/node/v14.15.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:904:46
45 verbose stack     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
45 verbose stack     at Arborist.[buildDepStep] (/Users/{ユーザー名}/.nodebrew/node/v14.15.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:904:8)
45 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (/Users/{ユーザー名}/.nodebrew/node/v14.15.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:217:7)
45 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
46 verbose cwd /Users/{ユーザー名}/Documents/Sandbox/｛プロジェクト名｝
47 verbose Darwin 20.3.0
48 verbose argv "/Users/{ユーザー名}/.nodebrew/node/v14.15.5/bin/node" "/Users/{ユーザー名}/.nodebrew/current/bin/npm" "install" "react-draggable"
49 verbose node v14.15.5
50 verbose npm  v7.8.0
51 error Invalid Version: ^4.0.0-alpha.57
52 verbose exit 1
```

## 参考資料リンク

1. [react-draggable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draggable)
2. [@material-ui/lab](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/lab)

以上です。
よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 0):

根本的な解決ではなく副次的問題が発生しますが、表題の問題は解決するということで下記で対応しました。
より良い解決策・原因の解明を引き続き募集いたします。

## 行ったこと

1. `@material-ui/lab`を`npm uninstall @material-ui/lab`でアンインストール
2. `react-draggable`を`npm install react-draggable`でインストール
3. `@material-ui/lab`を`npm install @material-ui/lab`で再インストール

## 懸念事項

`@material-ui/lab`のパッケージ指定を`*`から変えたのはGitHub Actionsの`npm ci && npm run build`でエラーが発生するからだったので、上記手法だとGitHub Actionsで再びエラーが発生するようになる。

エラー内容は下記。

```
npm ERR! cipm can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's @material-ui/lab@4.0.0-alpha.57 does not satisfy @material-ui/lab@*
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-04-26T08_08_31_976Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```